# How to write the XPath for this

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write the XPath for the below element but unable to do. I want to write for the Individual. I wrote like this `//h3[contains(text(),'Individual')]`

```
<h3 class="dashboradh">
          <strong>My Dashboard</strong>
          <span>Anjana</span> |  Individual        </h3>
```

Comment: Your h3 does not contain the text in question. You could go for //h3/strong[contains(text(), 'Individual')]/.. to get your Element but the css selector h3.dashboradh should be faster and more resistant against changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are some white spaces in your string. So use `normalize-space()` to trim the white spaces as below :

```
//h3[normalize-space(text()='Individual')]
```

**OR**

You should try dot `.` instead of `text()` in contains method to match the required text in any node within the tag.

```
//h3[contains(., 'Individual')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dot . like in previous comment. Dot will look for text in all child nodes. You can also be more specific:
**//h3//span[contains(text(),'Individual')]** or **//h3//*[contains(text(),'Individual')]** 
if you don't know type of child element.